# How to create a calculated field formula that connects a "yes" in a PivotTable field to a name in a different field that displays as a column value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, ms-office

I'm trying to create a PivotTable that shows each World series winner. I have the fields WSM (world series win) that is in Y/N format, year, and team name. I'm trying to get a "Y" in WSM to correlate with a team name that displays as a column value, but can't seem to think of the right formula.

Comment: This is too vague, you need to define the existing raw data defining world series winner (WSW NOT WSM?) And then describe the data where you want to refer to this raw data to pull the Yes No

Comment: @Jacob Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the guidelines to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example